# Retrofit not retrieving AccessToken

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, oauth-2.0, retrofit2

I have been following this tutorial as I have been advised that `Retrofit` is the best API to use for oAuth and network calls: 
[Retrofit oAuth2 tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/oauth-2-on-android-with-retrofit)

It seems to have been working well and I had retrieved my authorization code without any problems. However, when It came to using the code they supplied for exchanging it for an Access Token, I seem to be getting a `nullpointer` and being a total beginner with `Retrofit` I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

ServiceGenerator Class:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://xxxx.xxxx.com/oauth/";

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return createService(serviceClass, null);
}

public static <S> S createService(
        Class<S> serviceClass, String clientId, String clientSecret) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(clientId)
            && !TextUtils.isEmpty(clientSecret)) {
        String authToken = Credentials.basic(clientId, clientSecret);
        return createService(serviceClass, authToken);
    }

    return createService(serviceClass, null, null);
}

public static <S> S createService(
        Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        AuthenticationInterceptor interceptor =
                new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken);

        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(interceptor)) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            retrofit = builder.build();
        }
    }
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

}

AuthenticationInterceptor Class:

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private String authToken;

public AuthenticationInterceptor(String token) {
    this.authToken = token;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();

    Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", authToken);

    Request request = builder.build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
}
```

}

Access Token Class:

```
public class AccessToken {

private String accessToken;
private String tokenType;

public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}

public String getTokenType() {
    // OAuth requires uppercase Authorization HTTP header value for token type
    if (! Character.isUpperCase(tokenType.charAt(0))) {
        tokenType =
                Character
                        .toString(tokenType.charAt(0))
                        .toUpperCase() + tokenType.substring(1);
    }

    return tokenType;
}
```

}

Most importantly, my oAuth Class:

```
public class oAuthAuthentication extends Activity {
// you should either define client id and secret as constants or in string resources
private final String clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private final String clientSecret = "xxxxxxx";
private final String redirectUri = "https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/rest/callback.html";
private String AUTH_URL;
private String AuthCode;
String grantType;
AccessToken accessToken;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.oauth);

    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = AUTH_URL;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // the intent filter defined in AndroidManifest will handle the return from ACTION_VIEW intent
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(redirectUri)) {
            new AsyncTaskRunner().execute();
        } else {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error has occured with AuthCode");
        }
    }




public interface LoginService {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/oauth/token")
        Call<AccessToken> getAccessToken(
                @Field("code") String code,
                @Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                @Field("client_id") String clientID,
                @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
                @Field("redirect_uri") String redirectUri);

    }

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(redirectUri)) {
            // use the parameter your API exposes for the code (mostly it's "code")
            String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
            if (code != null) {
                AuthCode = code;
                LoginService loginService =
                        ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class, clientId, clientSecret);
                Call<AccessToken> call = loginService.getAccessToken(code, "authorization_code");
                try {
                    accessToken = call.execute().body();
                    Log.e("token", accessToken.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(accessToken);
    }
}
```

}

The AccessToken End-point I am trying to hit is https://xxxx.xxxx.com/oauth/token

Is there anyone who has used Retrofit for oAuth can help me with this?
P.s. I have checked all my values are correct, ID, Secret, Code is being generated fine and grant_type is supposed to equal "authorization_code" as stated.

Comment: Where's your refreshing token method? For example `getAccessToken()` method on `LoginService` interface.

Comment: im not sure. when I do control and click on the <AccessToken> it brings me to the AccessToken class above. However the methods are blank as in they haven't been used. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @dr3k I think its because I need to send more than just code and grant_type. but when I go to write more Fields in the interface it gives me errors. How can I fix this so I can add more?

Comment: What kind of errors? Can you show it to me?

Comment: @dr3k see above, I updated my interface as I need to send all of those in the request. However, still null :(

Comment: Maybe the response body does not match to your `AccessToken` object.

As I see in the code, you are returning the string value of `AccessToken` which is not a string at all.

Comment: @dr3k what would you suggest to fix this?

Comment: Well, I still don't know which part in your code is returning a `nullpointer`.

Comment: @dr3k It is only the AccessToken is getting null when I try to Toast it or Print it. if I don't then there is no errors, I just don't retrieve it and nothing happens

Comment: Are you using the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask`. I'm just wondering when and where did you try to access or show Toast message this `accessToken` in your code.

Comment: @dr3k yes on postexecute :)

Comment: Can you try this. I'm not gonna post this as answer though because it's not sure to work.

`private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, AccessToken> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
     AccessToken newAccessToken;
        /// ... some of your code
        try {
         newAccessToken = call.execute().body();
        }

        return newAccessToken;
    }

    @Override
    protected AccessToken onPostExecute(AccessToken result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            accessToken = result
        }
}`

Comment: I have tried that but still null. Where would I set content-type in this?

Comment: @dr3k this is the error I have been getting every time: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Its seems that `AccessToken` is null because your request is failing. When it failed from request, it gives you a different response from the API that your `AccessToken` is unable to convert.

Have check your API using Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/)? Is it working as expected, with the given parameter or field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174429/discussion-between-dr3k-and-aaron).